# Acessing Command prompt using Python for automated flow

Tags: python, command-line, automation, command-prompt

I need to run an executable file that works only with command prompt multiple times.It is used to retrieve data Information based on the Details of the framenumbers and it ranges only between 0 to any postive value. And I have this framenumber data in a Excel file and i want it to loop through the range of framenumber. This is the part of command `--start {framenumber1} --end {framenumber2}` where it should be changed for each execution. i also Need admin rights to run this executable.

Is there any possible way of automating this workflow in python for using the command prompt multiple times with slightly different Input? Any Suggestion would be very helpful

Comment: You can use `os.system("cd directory; <other commands here")` if you don't need to read the output

Comment: Hi thanks, there would be an Output of Image files generated after every execution

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution of using os.system() invoking to solve it. Here is the gist of code of how to Access the command prompt using python with admin Rights.

```
def is_admin():
try:
    return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
except:
    return False

if is_admin():
df=pd.read_excel(r'D:\final_xxxx.xlsx',sep=',')

for i,x in zip(df['framenumber'],df['C']):
  os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxxxxx\xxxv1.02\xxx\xxx.exe')))
    if i==i:
        k=math.trunc(i)
        j=k
        #executable operation running in python for command prompt till the loop ends
        os.system(r'xxxx.exe --file "D:\xxxx\2020-07-27_xxxxx.xxxx" --output "D:\xxxx" --start {} --end {}'.format(j,j))
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```